# Spiral Core Transformer

Tags: transformer

Presently, I am reading about different types of transformer. I am stuck on 'spiral core or wound core transformer'. I didn't find any good explanation about it in the textbook I am reading. Searched on the internet in hope to find more detail, but same thing, no good description.

I am providing the text from the book I am reading as follows:

In spiral core, **spirals of strip steel** are wound through the **window of perforated coil**. The resultant structure provides continuous magnetic path **unobstructed by butt or lap joints** hence the path of reluctance is reduced.

I don't understand the words in bold.
It will be helpful if it is possible to provide a picture for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a description of that is called "wound core" transformer. A single strip of magnetic material (silicon steel, for example) is wound into a core.

For example:

[image]

You can google butt joint and lap joint- a butt joint is just two flat edges pressed up against each other, a lap joint is stepped.

(image of E-I laminations below from [this](http://pe2bz.philpem.me.uk/Misc/-%20Audio/-%20Amp/-%20AudioAmpDesignInfo%20$$$/-%20AudioAmpBasics-001/B-002-Transformers-1+2/xfmr2.htm) web page):

[image: http://pe2bz.philpem.me.uk/Misc/-%20Audio/-%20Amp/-%20AudioAmpDesignInfo%20$$$/-%20AudioAmpBasics-001/B-002-Transformers-1+2/xfmr2.htm]

Seems pretty easy- certainly compared to stacking up dozens of E-I or E-E laminations (flipping the former each pair results in a kind of lap joint)- so why don't all metal core transformers use this?

You can see the obvious disadvantage- the wound core is topologically equivalent to a toroid- there's no way to slip an already-wound bobbin onto the core.

Comment: Is spiral core or wound core transformers are different? And what does "wound through the window of perforated coil" means?

Comment: I think they are the same thing. Perforated just means there is a hole. It's a bit awkward wording.